# How to schedule a task to execute 9000 seconds from now on?

Tags: windows, python, time, task-scheduler

I have a batch script that executes a few Python scripts and then needs to schedule the last Python script to be executed 9000 seconds later. Here's what I have so far: (I only know how to manually set a time)

> C:\> schtasks /create /tn StockRelease /tr D:\dev\autopilot\check_reservation_timeouts.py /sc once /st 10:14
>
> SUCCESS: The scheduled task "StockRelease" has successfully been created.

My question is, how do I calculate what time will be in 9000 seconds?

I am sure that this question has been answered somewhere, but I am most likely searching with wrong keywords.
I have checked Microsoft documentation https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785(v=ws.10).aspx and various SuperUser-questions.

Comment: You also may want to have a look at the sleep command: http://serverfault.com/questions/432322/how-to-sleep-in-a-batch-file

Comment: Sleep may cause unnecessary thread locking... Write a bat function to get current time when the main script completes and add on your 9000 seconds (2:30) to the variable (current time) and then you run the command line to create a one time scheduled task...

Comment: @user236012: That's right, it would work as well. I want to make it a Scheduled task so that the batch execution window would disappear, and not be present for 2,5 hours.

Comment: http://acoderslife.com/index.cfm/blog/Adding-XX-minutes-to-the-current-time-in-a-Windows-batch-file - change the "10" in the second line to 150 as that's 9000 seconds in minutes... You'll need to tailor that to suit your needs.

Comment: @BigChris Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken directly from someone's page who was after exactly this same requirement I have copied and pasted the code below:

```
::============================================
::GET THE CURRENT HOUR AND MINUTE + 10 MINUTES
::============================================
SET CURRENTTIME=%TIME%
for /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%h in ('echo %CURRENTTIME%') do (set /a HR=%%h)
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%m in ('echo %CURRENTTIME%') do (set /a MIN=%%m + 10)


::=======================================================
::IF THE MINUTE IS >= 60, ROLL IT OVER BY SUBSTRACTING 60
::FROM MINUTES AND ADDING 1 TO HOURS
::=======================================================
IF %MIN% GEQ 60 (
    SET /a MIN=%MIN%-60 
    SET /a HR=%HR%+1
)

::===========================================================================
::IF THE HOUR IS > 24, THEN IT IS BECAUSE WE ADDED 1 TO 24 ABOVE. SET IT TO 0
::===========================================================================
IF %HR% GTR 24 SET HR=00


::============================================
::PAD SINGLE DIGIT MINUTES WITH A LEADING ZERO
::============================================
IF %MIN% LEQ 9 (
    SET MIN=0%MIN%
)

::==========================================
::PAD SINGLE DIGIT HOURS WITH A LEADING ZERO
::==========================================
IF %HR% LEQ 9 (
    SET HR=0%HR%
)

::========================================================================
::USE THE NEW HOUR AND MINUTE (AND EXISTING SECONDS) TO CREATE THE NEW TIME
::========================================================================
SET NEWTIME=%HR%:%MIN%:%CURRENTTIME:~6,10%
```

Source: http://acoderslife.com/index.cfm/blog/Adding-XX-minutes-to-the-current-time-in-a-Windows-batch-file

You will need to tailor the rest to suit your requirements - i.e. set the scheduled task as a one-time task so that it doesn't repeat when you don't need it to. I would also write into your script [that executes when the scheduled task executes] to delete the scheduled task so you don't fill the scheduled task manager.